# User Define Database Connection In CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdo

I am new to Codeigniter and trying to connect to dynamic database define by user, like we normally do in PHP.

Currently i am able to connect to database by using the setting mention in user guide and trying to access it like..

```
class ModelTest extends CI_Model
{
    public function getdata()
    {
        $this->load->database();
        $q=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
        return $q->result();

    }
```

}

Now i want to access it using the database define by the user, not the default like we use normally..

```
class Database{

    // specify your own database credentials
    private $host = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=satudent_enrollement';
    private $username = 'root';
    private $password = '';
    public $conn;

    // get the database connection
    public function getConnection(){

        $this->conn = null;

        try{
            $this->conn = new PDO($this->host , $this->username, $this->password);
        }catch(PDOException $exception){
            echo "Connection error: " . $exception->getMessage();
        }

        return $this->conn;
    }
}
```

> **What I Want:**  To connect the Database using the database define by the user not the default.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: which version of codeigniter is this?

Comment: latest version 3.1.0

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Codeigniter User Guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#connecting-to-your-database//), you can manually pass database connectivity settings via the third parameter of `$this->load->model`:

```
$config['hostname'] = "mysql:host=localhost";
$config['username'] = "root";
$config['password'] = "XXX";
$config['database'] = "satudent_enrollement";
$config['dbdriver'] = "pdo";
$config['dbprefix'] = "";
$config['pconnect'] = FALSE;
$config['db_debug'] = TRUE;

$this->load->model('ModelTest', '', $config);

// or as gorelative notes, to access multiple databases:

$DB2 = $this->load->database($config, TRUE);
```

I hope it will work for you!!

Answer (score 0):

Use below setting in database.php for PDO in 2.x version

```
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'mysql:host=localhost';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'pdo';
$db['default']['database'] = 'satudent_enrollement';
```

hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but this is the default setting and it is working for me, i want the user define.. please read the question again.

Comment: Yhea den create a file and put in core which extends the default core and do your custom codings in  that file.